# Do I have to destroy manually created combo boxes on a dialog?

Tags: mfc

In `OnInitDialog` I call this method to create 9 `CComboBox` drop lists:

```
void CChristianLifeMinistryStudentsDlg::CreateSampleConversationVideoCombos()
{
    CChristianLifeMinistryStudentEdit* pArrayStudents[9] =
    {
        &m_editMainStudent1,
        &m_editMainStudent2,
        &m_editMainStudent3,
        &m_editClass1Student1,
        &m_editClass1Student2,
        &m_editClass1Student3,
        &m_editClass2Student1,
        &m_editClass2Student2,
        &m_editClass2Student3
    };

    CChristianLifeMinistryStudentEdit* pArrayAssistants[9] =
    {
        &m_editMainStudent1Assist,
        &m_editMainStudent2Assist,
        &m_editMainStudent3Assist,
        &m_editClass1Student1Assist,
        &m_editClass1Student2Assist,
        &m_editClass1Student3Assist,
        &m_editClass2Student1Assist,
        &m_editClass2Student2Assist,
        &m_editClass2Student3Assist
    };

    CString strChairman, strAuxClassCounsellor;

    strChairman.LoadString(IDS_STR_MWB_CHAIRMAN);
    strAuxClassCounsellor.LoadString(IDS_STR_AUX_CLASS_COUNSELLOR);

    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    {
        CRect rctStudent, rctAssistant;

        pArrayStudents[i]->GetWindowRect(rctStudent);
        pArrayAssistants[i]->GetWindowRect(rctAssistant);

        ScreenToClient(&rctStudent);
        ScreenToClient(&rctAssistant);

        CRect rctSampleConversationVideo;

        rctSampleConversationVideo.SetRect(rctStudent.TopLeft(), rctAssistant.BottomRight());
        m_cbSampleConversationVideo[i].Create(CBS_DROPDOWN | WS_VSCROLL | WS_TABSTOP | WS_VISIBLE,
            rctSampleConversationVideo, this, IDC_COMBO_OCLM_AYFM_ASSIGN1_MH + i);

        m_cbSampleConversationVideo[i].SetFont(GetFont());
        m_cbSampleConversationVideo[i].AddString(strChairman);
        m_cbSampleConversationVideo[i].AddString(strAuxClassCounsellor);
    }
}
```

What I can't work out is if I need to call `DestroyWindow` on each of these when the dialog is closed? I don't seem to get any memory leaks.

Comment: Your code is not clear. But generally no. `DestroyWindow` is not meant for dialog controls. Dialog controls usually don't need special cleanup.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you have a window handled by the MFC you have two parts. The first is the window itself (represented by the `HWND`), the second is the object in the MFC that wraps the functionality implements a message map and offers easy member function access by wrapping the windows messages.

The lifetime of a window ends when `DestroyWindow` is called. A parent window like a dialog will destroy all it child windows automatically. It doesn't matter if the child was created by calling `CreateDialog`/`DoModal`, or created later using any other `Create` method.

Finally all windows are destroyed when the process ends. In fact all windows created inside a thread are destroyed when the thread ends. But windows should be destroyed by the user before the thread ends.

The MFC memory block is another thing. Some MFC windows are designed to be allocated on the stack or inside a window class as a member.

Dialogs and all windows that are usually created as a child windows (static, list view, buttons, etc.) are created on the stack or as a member inside another window class.

Also all this window that are designed to live on the stack or as a member call `DestroyWindow` when the destructor of the class is called and if the window still exists. This also causes a message on the debug output and usually this should be avoided.

Frame windows and views are created on the heap. All MFC windows that are created on the heap have have a `PostNcDestroy` function that finally deletes the MFC memory block, when `WM_DESTROY` was handled. `PostNcDestroy` is always called from the `WM_NCDESTROY` handler.

You find details about this also in [TN017](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/cpp/mfc/tn017-destroying-window-objects) in the MSDN